# Is there any way to scheduled publish message on pubnub

Tags: pubnub

How I Publish massage on specific date time.like google gmail provide schedule for send email.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific API to say 'schedule at' a specific time, you would need to manage that in your app yourself with a timer / alarm (depending on what  platform you're developing for)

Answer (score 0):

## Scheduling a Message for the Future

[image: Schedule a Message]

A simple way to schedule a future message is using an `On Interval` function. Create a new function using the "Time On Interval" type.  Set the interval to `60000` milliseconds.  This will check every minute to see if there is a message to be sent.

[image: Time On Interval Schedule a Message]

Copy the code snippet shown in this StackOverflow answer and paste it into the function code editor in your PubNub Account.  Update the `send_at` variable to target your future date.  Time zone is GMT/UTC.

```js
let send_at = Date.parse('19 May 2022 02:00:00');
```

Function snippet follows:

```js
const pubnub = require('pubnub');
export default (event) => {

  // Send future message at this time
  let send_at = Date.parse('19 May 2022 02:00:00'); // <-- CHANGE ME

  let current_minute = getMinute();
  let future_minute = getMinute(send_at);
  let countdown = future_minute - current_minute;
  console.log(`Sending in: ${countdown} minutes.`, send_at, current_minute, future_minute);

  // Send future message
  if (countdown === 0) pubnub.publish({
    channel: "future",
    message: "Hello future!"
  });

  return event.ok();
};

function getMinute(date) {
  return Math.round((date || +new Date) / 60000);
}
```

[image: Schedule messages to be sent in the future]

The code snippet above as written will allow you to send one message in the future.  However if you alter the JavaScript you can send more messages.  There is also a [KV store module](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/functions/kvstore-module) which you can use as a database to store more messages to be sent in the future.  You can create another function module `On Request` which saves messages to the database to be sent later.

```js
const db = require("kvstore");
let send_at = Date.parse(__FUTURE_TIME_UTC_CHANGE_ME__);
let future_minute = getMinute(send_at);
db.setItem(future_minute, {"message":"my message"});
```

And in our original `On Interval` function we can use the following:

```js
const db = require("kvstore");
let current_minute = getMinute();
let message = await db.getItem(current_minute);

if (message) pubnub.publish({
  channel: "future",
  message: message
});
```